# Why is an array's dimension part of its type?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

While reading the C++ Primer book, I came across this statement: "The number of elements in an array is part of the array's type." So I wanted to find out using the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    char Array1[]{'H', 'e', 'l', 'p'};
    char Array2[]{'P', 'l', 'e', 'a', 's', 'e'};

    std::cout<<typeid(Array1).name()<<std::endl;        //prints  A4_c
    std::cout<<typeid(Array2).name()<<std::endl;        //prints  A6_c

    return 0;
}
```

And interestingly the result of typeid on the two arrays showed they are somehow different.

- What's going on behind the scenes?
- Why is it necessary to for array's to have a type that includes its size? Is it just because its size should not change?
- How will this affect comparing arrays?

Just want to be able to deeply understand the concept.

Comment: It's not strictly _necessary_ to include size information in the type, but it's useful

Comment: Any tutorial on arrays will explain (1). I'm not sure what do you mean by (3), since there is no builtin way to compare arrays.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What's going on behind the scenes?

A non dynamically-allocated is, by definition, a **fixed-size** container of homogeneous elements. An array of `N` elements of type `T` is laid out in memory as a contiguous sequence of `N` objects of type `T`.

---

> Why is it necessary to for array's to have a type that includes it's size?

I do not believe it is "necessary" for an array's type to include it's size - as a matter of fact, you can use a pointer to refer to a contiguous sequence of `T` objects. Such pointer would lose size information about the array.

It is, however, a useful thing to have. It improves type safety, and encodes useful information at compile-time that can be used in multiple ways. As an example, you can use *references-to-arrays* to overload on arrays of different sizes

```
void foo(int(&array)[4]) { /* ... */ }
void foo(int(&array)[8]) { /* ... */ }
```

or to figure out the size of an array as a constant expression

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto sizeOf(const T(&array)[N]) { return N; }
```

---

> How will this affect comparing arrays?

It doesn't, really.

You cannot compare C-style arrays in the same way you would compare two numbers (e.g. `int` objects). You would have to write some sort of lexicographical comparison, and decide what it means for collections of different sizes. [`std::vector<T>` provides that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp), and the same logic can be applied to arrays.

---

**Bonus:** C++11 and above provides [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is a wrapper around a C-style array with a container-like interface. It should be preferred to C-style arrays as it is more consistent with other containers (e.g. `std::vector<T>`), and also supports [lexicographical comparisons](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) out of the box.

Comment: "You would have to write some sort of lexicographical comparison, and decide what it means for collections of different sizes." You could just use `std::equal` (via `std::begin` and `std::end` which are defined for arrays). In that case, different sized arrays are non-equal.

Comment: It might be worth noting that range-based for loops whose range is an array need to read the size of the array at compile time - it's a bit subtler since (thankfully!) one never writes out the type of the array in this example, but it seems comes up a lot more than overloading based on size.

Answer (score 8):

The amount of space that is allocated to an object when you create it depends entirely on its type. The allocation I'm talking about isn't allocations from `new` or `malloc`, but the space that is allocated so that you can run your constructor and initialize your object.

If you have a struct defined as (for example)

```
struct A { char a, b; }; //sizeof(A) == 2, ie an A needs 2 bytes of space
```

Then when you construct the object:

```
A a{'a', 'b'};
```

You can think of the process of constructing the object as a process:

- Allocate 2 bytes of space (on the stack, but where doesn't matter for this example)
- Run object's constructor (in this case copy `'a'` and `'b'` to the object)

It's important to note that the 2 bytes of space needed is entirely determined by the type of the object, the arguments to the function don't matter. So, for an array the process is the same, except now the amount of space needed depends on the number of elements in the array.

```
char a[] = {'a'}; //need space for 1 element
char b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}; //need space for 5 elements
```

So the types of `a` and `b` must reflect the fact that `a` needs enough space for 1 char and `b` needs enough space for 5 chars. That does mean that the size of these arrays cannot suddenly change, once a 5-element array is created it is always a 5-element array. In order to have "array"-like objects where the size can vary, you need dynamic memory allocation, which your book should be cover at some point.

Answer (score 0):

It's for an internal reason for the runtime library. If you consider the following statements, for instance:

```
unsigned int i;
unsigned int *iPtr;
unsigned int *iPtrArr[2];
unsigned int **iPtrHandle;
```

Then it becomes clear what the problem is: For instance, the addressing of `unsigned int *` has to concern itself with the `sizeof operator` or addressing of `unsigned int`.

There is a more detailed explanation for the rest of what you see here, but it is largely a recapitulation of what was covered in the *C Programming Language, 2nd Edition* by Kernighan and Ritchie concerning the program that prints the plain language text of the declared type string.